# How do I get the event.keyCode of the delete key?

Tags: events, keypress, keycode

```
$('body').keypress(function(event){

     if(event.keyCode == 46){console.log('Delete Key Pressed')}; //does not work

     if(event.keyCode == 32){console.log('SPACE BAR')}; //works
})
```

[Why doesn't the delete key show up in THIS FIDDLE ?](http://jsfiddle.net/5cNTn/5/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Instead of keypress, use the keyup or keydown event: keypress is meant for PRINTABLE characters, whereas keydown will capture non-printing key presses including delete, backspace, and return.
http://jsfiddle.net/5cNTn/9/

```
$('body').keydown(function(event){
    var letter = String.fromCharCode(event.which); 
    if(event.keyCode == 32){console.log('SPACE BAR');}
    if(event.keyCode == 46){console.log('Delete Key Pressed');}
    console.log(event); 
    console.log(event.keyCode); 
 });
```

Comment: Nice.  Will backspace or delete have effects on the browser window that I could cancel?

Comment: Yep! In some browsers backspace returns to the previous page- preventDefault can help.

Comment: Like this `if(event.keyCode == 46){event.preventDefault(); console.log('Delete Key Pressed');}` ?

Comment: yep! But keep in mind that this may also impact pressing backspace to delete text in editable input fields :-)

Comment: That is good info on keypress vs keydown for printable characters.

Answer (score 13):

## Use keydown and modern JS!

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "Delete") {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

### Modern style, lambda + destructuring

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", ({key}) => {
    if (key === "Delete") {
        // Do something
    }
})
```